# Formatting bar right aligned before anonymously answering

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, answers, anonymous

If you're not logged in, you see this at the bottom of every question:

> [image]

Those icons should be left aligned. In addition to this I noticed that there is more alignment weirdness happening once you give the answer box focus:

> [image]

While the icons are correctly left aligned, the "your answer" instruction box is a little too wide and also overlaps the formatting toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

These should be fixed now. There was some work done a few months back to prepare the editor for the pending responsive redesign, and the placeholder markup (the full editor doesn't load until it is clicked) was neglected in this update.

I left the width of the pop-up alone, as it appears to be intentional and altering it may break some themes; it'll likely need to be redesigned anyway when we move to a responsive layout.

Thanks for reporting this!